# Add value from select to scope without defining ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to grab values from a select and add them to scope and keep them updated which I would normally do via `ng-model` without a problem.  The problem is that I need this select to NOT be angular powered due to my required workflow.

The problem I am running into is how to add the `ng-model` reference without getting the blank option that gets added because I am not feeding it any ng-options array.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am after? I understand that the empty default value gets added because I have not defined any options and/or `options.language` does not exist by default in my scope, my questions is, can I get around this somehow?

The end goal here is to be able to tag this controller onto any form, tag the selects with `ng-model="options.myOption"`, and get all of those options on demand at any time in the scope of the controller.

Test markup:

```
<select name="language" ng-model="options.language">
    <option value="en_US">English</option>
    <option value="fr_FR">French</option>
    <option value="es_ES">Spanish</option>
    <option value="de_DE">German</option>
    <option value="zh_CN">Chinese</option>
    <option value="ja_JP">Japanese</option>
</select>
```

Test javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){
    $scope.options=[];
    $scope.$watch("options.language", function(){
        $log.log($scope.options.language);
    });
}])
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CgRZn/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'NOT be angular powered'. If you want the default to show up as English you can just put `$scope.options = { language: 'us_EN' }` but you seem to not be able to do that. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I COULD do that, but it would be a bit of a pain for the back end developers.  I'm basically hoping for a way for angular to pick up on the default selected option and add that as the current value for the drop-down in the scope initially, and then update from there as the user changes the input.

Comment: How about with the `ng-init` directive like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/CgRZn/3/). The initial value is assigned right from the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-init` directive to assign the default to your scope without touching the script. Like this:

```
<select name="language" ng-model="options.language" ng-init="options.language='en_US'">
    <option value="en_US">English</option>
    <option value="fr_FR">French</option>
    <option value="es_ES">Spanish</option>
    <option value="de_DE">German</option>
    <option value="zh_CN">Chinese</option>
    <option value="ja_JP">Japanese</option>
</select>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CgRZn/3/)

Comment: This was my original solution, I was just trying to find a way around having to define the default value at all and have angular pick it up from the selected object automatically to make it easier for the back end guys when they are generating the markup.

Technically though this IS the /correct/ way of doing things.

Comment: If you want to do it that way, you would probably need to add a step where you parse the html file and insert the angular attributes. Since it would be the back-end guys that would have to implement that tho, you might need to just bite the bullet and tell them that they need to add a couple extra attributes when generating the markup. Angular is very much wedded to the markup, so if you really need the app logic out of your markup you might want a different framework. I wish you luck.